# INNER JOIN for login form doesn't seem to work in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Let me first explain what i'm trying to do...

I have two Tables in mysql database. 1st is `members` and the other one is `storename`.

I save a random unique Key in both of these tables in the column `randKey`.

This all works fine.

Now, I have a login form which I am trying to use which has `INNER JOIN` in the `SELECT`.

the purpose of using **INNER JOIN** is to be able to use the `randKey` in both Tables mentioned above so the users cannot login to someone else's account if you know what I mean.

only if the `email`, `password` and `randKey` is matched then they can login?

However, when I run the PHP/login page and try to login, I get `That information is incorrect, try again` echoed out to me...

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["email"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "config/connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT members.email, members.password, storename.email, storename.password
FROM `members`
INNER JOIN `storename`
ON (members.randKey = storename.randKey)"; 
// query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    if (!$query) {
    die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
}
    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: dashboard");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="login">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no filters in your query, so it's returning every row of your database. You probably have more than one member, so the number of rows can't be equal to `1`.

The second problem is that you're not selecting any id in your query, but you're trying to get if after.

Try this :

```
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["email"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "config/connect.php";

    $sql = "
        SELECT members.id
        FROM `members`
        INNER JOIN `storename` ON (members.randKey = storename.randKey)
        WHERE members.email = '$manager'
        AND members.password = '$password'
    ";
    // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    if (!$query) {
        die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    }
    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
        $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        header("location: dashboard");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="login">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you don't have a where clause so your query fetches all of the rows which is probably bigger than 1.